# org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1

Tags: maven, jbossfuse, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

I used mvn clean install to build rest project in quick-start examples in jboss fuse,and deployed it using mvn fabric8:deploy but when I assign this profile to a container, it has a error: I searched a lot to find the solution,but I don't know which feature or artifact has error

```
Provision Exception:

    io.fabric8.common.util.MultiException: Error

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.(MavenDownloadManager.java:93)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:71)

      at io.fabric8.agent.service.Agent.loadResources(Agent.java:626)

      at io.fabric8.agent.service.Agent.provision(Agent.java:212)

      at io.fabric8.agent.service.Agent.provision(Agent.java:199)

      at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:753)

      at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$4.run(DeploymentAgent.java:303)

      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1

      at io.fabric8.agent.resolver.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:72)

      at io.fabric8.agent.resolver.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:65)

      at io.fabric8.agent.service.Agent$3.downloaded(Agent.java:633)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader$1.operationComplete(MavenDownloadManager.java:143)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader$1.operationComplete(MavenDownloadManager.java:137)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.DefaultFuture.notifyListener(DefaultFuture.java:343)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.DefaultFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultFuture.java:328)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.DefaultFuture.setValue(DefaultFuture.java:254)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.AbstractDownloadTask.setFile(AbstractDownloadTask.java:53)

      at io.fabric8.agent.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:41)

      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)

      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)

      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve the problem, in fuse terminal write this command:
profile-display *profile-name*

the result shows:
Agent Properties : 
      optional.mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jsonSchema/2.4.3 = mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jsonSchema/2.4.3
      lastRefresh.quickstarts-cxf-rest = 1564925509134
      optional.fab:mvn:com.wordnik/swagger-jaxrs_2.10/1.3.12 = fab:mvn:com.wordnik/swagger-jaxrs_2.10/1.3.12

In fuse V6.3 fab is not working any more and you should wrap the bundle: 
so in fuse console, open profile's agent properties and make optional.fab commented

the problem will be solved